# Electric shadow-hand error with haptic glove

Tags: ros, shadow-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
i create a pkg for an haptic glove few months ago, on ros fuerte version and was working very nice with shadow robot (shadow_hand).  for some reasons i had to install ROS electric version. i installed also the shadow- robot for electric but it don't works.

i think and suppose is for the dependencies that aren't on ros electric like sr_teleop, now the problem is , how to install sr_teleop on ros electric. cause an overlay was very problematic too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54254/electric-shadow-hand-error-with-haptic-glove/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you consider upgrading to Fuerte? Our latest stacks are released in fuerte (sr-teleop etc...). You can install them by simply running:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-shadow-robot ros-fuerte-sr-visualization ros-fuerte-sr-teleop
```

If you really want to install them on electric, see my answer to [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/53819/how-to-install-shadow_hand-in-ros-electric).

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-05**:
i was working on fuerte, and don't have problems with shadow, but i had it with gazebo, cause i need the collision too, and gazebo's fuerte version  don't work.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-05**:
right, then I'd suggest to go with the source install. Is this working for you?

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-05**:
the source install for gazebo? i tried many times but that failed, many erros.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-05**:
No, the source install for our code under electric. Never managed to get gazebo working from sources either... :S

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-05**:
mm no, i don't know what is the code source for shadow. and why you say dont get gazebo from sources?  well i get some errors, so i install ubuntu one more time, with ros electric now and these is my 4th time intented get working gazebo with collision+shadow-robot(sr_hand) + haptic glove. :'(

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-05**:
I think there's a misunderstanding :S I'm pointing you to another thread where I give a rosinstall file which can be used to install our code from sources under ROS electric. Is the problem that you don't know how to use the rosinstall file?

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-05**:
ok that sounds better, and you're right really i don't know how to use rosinstall file . thnks

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-05**:
edited the other thread. Can we continue the conversation there? It'll be better.

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-05**:
sorry, on wich thread? or i  make other question ? thnk u

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-02-05**:
as pointed above: http://answers.ros.org/question/53819/how-to-install-shadow_hand-in-ros-electric